# Why is there a stack overflow

Tags: c, stack, local-storage

Under Linux start with

```
ulimit -s 1024
```

to limit the stack size.

First of all a program which works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int calc(int c,int *array)
{
    if (array!=NULL) {
        if (c<=0) {
            array[0]=1;
            return 1;
        }
        calc(c-1,array);
        array[c]=array[c-1]+3;
        return array[c];
    } else {
        int a[2500+c];
        calc(c-1,a);
        a[c]=a[c-1]+3;
        return a[c];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int result;
    result = calc(1000,NULL);
    printf("result = %d\n",result);
}
```

Now if I change `int a[2500+c];` to `int a[2500];` then the program crashes with a stack overflow (segmentation fault).

I tried this with

- gcc-4.4.7 -O0, gcc-4.4.7 -O2, gcc-4.4.7 -O3
- gcc-4.8.4 -O0, gcc-4.8.4 -O2, gcc-4.8.4 -O3
- gcc-4.9.3 -O0, gcc-4.9.3 -O2, gcc-4.9.3 -O3

If I use

```
ulimit -s 1024
```

then the version with `int a[2500];` crashes, whereas the version with `int a[2500+c];` works.

Why does the version of the program which uses a variable length array (`int a[2500+c];`) consume less stack space than the version which uses a fixed length array (`int a[2500];`) ?

Comment: Note: The program will also work for both cases if you (for example) use `calc(20,NULL);` in main. The 2nd version (with the fixed length array) just uses **lots** more stack.

Comment: Both versions run without error for me.

Comment: John: Which compiler ?

Comment: I can reproduce this with gcc 4.8.4 `-O0`. On `-O3` both versions work fine. The reason is that the compiler unconditionally allocates the `int a[2500];` with `-O0` in the function prologue, without checking `array != NULL`

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.4.7 on Linux, with default options.  And I've tried eliciting a stack overflow by increasing the argument to the initial `calc()` call and by increasing the size of array `a`, but no luck after increasing both by a factor of 100 (at the same time).

Comment: perhaps if you say `a[2500]` the compiler will try and put the array on the stack, but if you say `a[2500+c]` it will use the heap, since the size of a isn't known at compile time.

Comment: One moment please, I have to try out with gcc 4.4 maybe only the more recent gcc versions have a problem...

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: `if (c<=0) {
            array[0]=1;
            return 1;
        }` looks terminatey to me.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Yes there is (albeit not perfect): `if (c<=0)...`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, the fact that the function in fact terminates contradicts your analysis.

Comment: John: For me it still crashes with gcc-4.4 and Ubuntu 14.04. What OS do you use ? Maybe there is a difference ? Note: If you use `ulimit -s 1024` before you run the program with `int a[2500];` does it still not crash ?

Comment: FYI, this is a follow-up to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974056/when-exactly-is-stack-allocated).

Comment: @dbush: yes: I did not get an answer and now tried to condense this to the part which is really baffling: Why does the `int a[2500];` version use **more** stack than the `int a[2500+c];` version ?

Comment: @IngoBlackman, I'm using CentOS 6.8.  I can reproduce the behavior you describe if I set `ulimit -s 1024`, including the variation between the two versions of your code.

Comment: @John: Thank you for trying out. I guess CentOS has a much higher stack usage limit per default. So the problem is not triggered there (Ubuntu 14.04 seems to use 8MiB per default and this seems to be too small already...)

Comment: @EOF: I just tried with gcc-4.8.4 with -O3; if I use `int a[2500];` I still get a crash. I agree: The compiler seems to allocate the space for `int a[2500]` without checking for `array!=NULL`. But why ? Why is space allocated for an array which is out of scope ?

Comment: As was mentioned in the previous question, "why" is an implementation detail of the compiler.  The standard doesn't dictate how the stack is laid out (or if there even is a stack).  You're better off using `malloc` in this case instead of using a local array.  That will give you more deterministic behavior.

Comment: @dbush: Forget about the stack. Why is the compiler allocating space (doesn't matter if it's stack or whatever) for a variable which is out of scope ? Do I simply have to assume that the compiler might allocate space for ALL variables in the program (even if they are out of scope) ?

Comment: I can't speak for the gcc developers, but I looked at the generated code, and there is one efficiency advantage when it allocates as many auto variables as possible upon function entry: the variables can be referenced as fixed offsets from the frame pointer. You'll see instructions like `mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-10032+rax*4]` for `array[c]`, whereas for `a[c]` the compiler first has to load its start address, `mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]` then do `mov eax, DWORD PTR [rax+rdx*4]`

Answer (score 4):

As was mentioned in the comments of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974056/when-exactly-is-stack-allocated), "why" is an implementation detail of the compiler. The standard doesn't dictate how the stack is laid out (or if there even is a stack).  As you've seen different versions of the same compiler, or the same version with different optimization settings, can alter how the compiler does things under the hood.

That being said, the compiler probably allocates stack space for all variables that are declared anywhere in the function that are not VLAs when the function is entered.  It's probably more efficient in some way that's opaque to the developer.  With a VLA, the size isn't known until runtime, so it's allocated differently.

You're better off using malloc in this case instead of using a local array. That will give you more deterministic behavior.

```
....
} else {
    int *a = malloc(c * sizeof(int));
    if (a == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    calc(c-1,a);
    a[c]=a[c-1]+3;
    int rval = a[c];
    free(a);
    return rval;
}
```

Comment: Your answer basically boils down to: The compiler might allocate space (it does not matter if it's stack) for any variable mentioned somewhere in the program, even if the variable in question is out of scope. How is that an answer ? You basically say there are no guarantees whatsoever how much space the compiler might allocate for variables out of scope for code which is never run...

Comment: @IngoBlackman Precisely.  There are no guarantees, at least not within the scope of a given function.

Comment: @4386427: If I write something like `int *p; { int a[10]; p=&(a[0]); } *p=5;` this is undefined behavior, because `a` is out of scope when I access it via `*p`. It's not allowed to access `a` anymore because it is not "valid" at the time I access it via `*p`. So why should there still be space allocated for `a` if the standard tells me accessing `a` is undefined behavior ?

Comment: @dbush: So if I write `int myfunc() { a[1000000000]; }` and I never call `myfunc()` then the compiler might still allocate space for `a`, because as you say "there are no guarantees". That is not exactly convincing.

Comment: @4386426 because the program in my question crashes; it would not crash if there would be no space allocated for `a`.

Comment: @IngoBlackman No guarantees within the scope of a given function call.  The compiler knows at compile time what variables are used in a function, so when the function is called it sets aside memory for those variables.  As I said, setting aside the memory at the start of the function call is probably more efficient in some opaque way than allocating and deallocating them as local scopes are entered / exited.

Comment: @dbush: And how do you know there are guarantees for variables from functions which are **not** called ? After all the compiler knows about these other functions so why not just allocate space for all local variables, not just for the function which is currently executed. According to your reasoning there are "no guarantees". So how do you come to the conclusion that there are guarantees for local variables that are declared in other functions ?

Comment: @dbush: "... the compiler knows at compile time what variables are used in a function." Well that's plainly wrong in the example I gave. Because it is **not** known at compile time if `int a[];` is used. It might never get into scope...

Comment: @IngoBlackman  Bad wording on my part.  It should have been "what variables exist in a function".

Comment: @dbush: And the compiler knows "what variables exist" in the program. So why doesn't it allocate space for all (local) variables which exist in the program ? I argue that the compiler should allocate space for variables which are in scope, whereas you argue that is just an implementation detail and the compiler might also allocate space for all variables which exist. Why do you limit your reasoning to variables "within a function" ? Why not all (local) variables which exist ?

Comment: @4386427: But that's saying I have to assume a compiler might allocate space for **any** variable which exists somewhere in the program. I do not believe that is a reasonable assumption...

Comment: @IngoBlackman Because if a function is called multiple times (as in your program), there is a copy of those variables for *each* invocation of the function.  So how would the compiler know how many to set aside?

Comment: @dbush: And now we are back to square one: Why should the compiler allocate space for a variable simply because it exists, even if it is out of scope ? To answer your question: The compiler could simply multiply the required space for all variables by 100 and thus limit the maximum recursion depth to 100. That's not really a problem because there anyway is a practical limit on the recursion depth. Note: The compiler obviously is able to generate a **different** strategy if I use `int a[2500+c];`, so why is the same strategy not used if I use `int a[2500];`

Comment: @4386427: Out of interest what compiler do you use ? I am still trying to figure out if that's only gcc related. What OS ?

Comment: @4386427: I actually checked the assembly. That's how this question originally arose: It turns out the compiler allocates stack at the function entry when i use `int a[2500];` but it does **not** allocate stack at the function entry when I use `int a[2500+c];` and that's the part which really got me wondering what's going on...

Comment: @4386427: Hmmmmm have you also tried with the `uname -s 1024` ? It turns out not every (linux) system has a strict limit on stack usage. So you must ensure a strict stack limit by first calling `uname -s 1024`